# Moving Between UITableViewController Detail Items

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segue, detailsview

I have a tableView and when the user selects a cell, a detail view is loaded. I want to allow the user to navigate throughout the detail views representing the items in the tableView by clicking either a previous button or a next button. How can I implement this into my detail view controller?

Answer (score 1):

Make the detailViewController a horizontal CollectionView with paging enabled and the same datasource as the parent viewController.  You just pass in the current indexPath in your segue and scroll to that indexPath in viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the same `datasource` from your `tableViewController` to `detailViewController`. Also pass the index of the selected `tableViewCell` to `detailViewController` from `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath).` Now when user click on next or previous button on `detailViewController` update your selected Index. Increment or decrement `selectedIndex` based on next or previous button clicked. Get the current `object` from the array based on `selectedIndex` and update your UI.

```
@IBAction func nextButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    selectedIndex += 1
}
```

```
@IBAction func previousButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    selectedIndex -= 1
}
```

```
func updateDetailView() {
    object = dataSource[selectedIndex]
}
```

Comment: Data is being downloaded from JSON file and populated into the tableview.

Comment: what is your datasource in ```func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int```